# Select from table excluding values from table2?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried make query for get data from table `log` excluding data from table `userlog`:

```
SELECT * FROM (`log`) LEFT JOIN `userlog` ON `userlog`.`userlogIdLog` = `log`.`LogId` 

WHERE (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 1) OR (logTypeCategory = 19 AND LogType = 1) 
OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 4) OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 8)
OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 12) OR (logTypeCategory = 2 AND LogType = 3)
OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 7) OR (logTypeCategory = 459 AND LogType = 9) 
OR (logTypeCategory = 456 AND LogType = 3) 

AND `userlogStatus` is null or userlogStatus <> 1 
AND `userlog`.`userlogIdUser` = '458' ORDER BY `LogId` DESC
```

But this query shows me rows from `log` although in table `userlog`  exists row with:  `userlogIdLog = 1 AND userlogStatus = 1 AND userlogIdUser = 458`

I edit with your help:

```
select * from `log` as a 
where not exists ( select 1 from `userlog` as b where b.`userlogIdLog` = a.`LogId` AND b.`userlogIdUser` = 458 ) 

 AND (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 1)

 OR (logTypeCategory = 19 AND LogType = 1)
 OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 4) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 8) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 12) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 2 AND LogType = 3) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 7) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 459 AND LogType = 9) 
 OR (logTypeCategory = 456 AND LogType = 3)
```

But this does not work correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to select data from one table where that data's not in another table:

e.g.

```
select *
from `log`
where `LogId` not in 
(
    select `userlogIdLog`
    from `userlog`
)
```

or

```
select *
from `log` as a
where not exists 
(
    select 1
    from `userlog` as b
    where b.`userlogIdLog` = a.`LogId`
)
```

... then after your choice of the above statements, add the rest of your logic; i.e.

```
AND 
(
       (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 1)
    OR (logTypeCategory = 19 AND LogType = 1)
    OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 4) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 8) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 12) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 2 AND LogType = 3) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 7) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 459 AND LogType = 9) 
    OR (logTypeCategory = 456 AND LogType = 3)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! And add `WHERE` `(logTypeCategory = 0 AND LogType = 1)` for first query?

Comment: Yes; only replace `WHERE` with `AND` as the above queries already have the `WHERE` statement.  In addition, put brackets around everything after the `AND` to avoid the `OR` statements from bypassing the check that these items aren't in the other table.  No worries.

Answer (score 1):

```
select L.col1,L.col2,L.col3 From Log L Left Outer Join userlog UL on L.LogId = UL.userlogIdLog where UL.userlogIdLog is NULL
```